# Executable file recreated from byte array cannot run due to incompatibility with 64-bit version of Windows

Tags: c#

I'm storing an .exe file in the resources of my console application as a File. I have a function to read the binary data of the file and then I re-create a file out of it:

```
private static byte[] GetScriptFromResources(string fileName)
{
    byte[] data = null;
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    Stream fileStream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(ResourceStream);

    if (fileStream != null)
    {
        var resourceReader = new System.Resources.ResourceReader(fileStream);

        resourceReader.GetResourceData(fileName, out string _, out data);
    }

    return data;
}

var myFile = GetScriptFromResources(MyResourceName);
File.WriteAllBytes(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\" + myFile + ".exe", myFile );
```

When I run myFile.exe I get an error that "Unsupported 16-Bit Application" and "unable to run due to incompatibility with 64-bit version of Windows"

If I run the original myFile.exe, it works but it does not work if I recreate it from the byte array. How can I recreate the file with same bit version as it was originally?

Comment: is the exe that you reconstructed byte-for-byte identical with the original? it doesn't sound like it, but: check

Comment: It is possible that the data in your resource file is incorrect, that it was saved in the resource file as a string or was saved with a Byte Order Mark (leftover from string reading). Use a hex editor and check for differences between your original exe, what is saved in the resource file and what the output your program.

Comment: If you're just looking to embed an exe (as a series of bytes) inside your console app, it's a lot easier to add it to your project as the type "Embedded Resource", then use `assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("nameOfFile.exe")` to get a stream containing that file's contents, which you can write out directly to a file on disk

Comment: I used a hex editor and yes, there was a difference between the original and the re-created file. It looks like it comes from my function to get the byte array. I tried another method which was MyConsoleApp.Properties.Resources.myFile to get the byte array and this worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I used a hex editor to see if there was a difference between the original and re-created file and there was.

If I get the byte array using this statement instead:

```
byte[] myFileByteArray = MyConsoleApp.Properties.Resources.myFile
```

instead of using my function, and re-create the file, the hex editor shows no differences and the executable works as the original one.